# Removing 'Not Available' from a .csv file in R

Tags: r, csv, na

I am trying to remove 'Not Available' from a .csv file using R. I have already figured out how to narrow down my file and arrange the data but the Not availables are not being removed. I have tried using complete.cases, na.omit and lapply and none of them work. Any help on this would be appreciated.See below for the assignment:

"Write a function called best that take two arguments: the 2-character abbreviated name of a state and an
outcome name. The function reads the outcome-of-care-measures.csv file and returns a character vector
with the name of the hospital that has the best (i.e. lowest) 30-day mortality for the specified outcome
in that state. The hospital name is the name provided in the Hospital.Name variable. The outcomes can
be one of “heart attack”, “heart failure”, or “pneumonia”. Hospitals that do not have data on a particular
outcome should be excluded from the set of hospitals when deciding the rankings"

```
best <- function(state, outcome)
{
  chart <- read.csv("outcome-of-care-measures.csv", colClasses = "character")
  
  if (!any(state == chart$State)){
    stop("invalid state")
  } else if(!outcome %in% c("heart attack" , "heart failure" , "pneumonia")){
    stop("invalid outcome")
  } else {
    keys <- c("heart attack" = 11, "heart failure" = 17, "pneumonia" = 23)
    outcomeKey <- keys[outcome]
  }
  
  dataByState <- split(chart, chart$State)
  outcomeState <- dataByState[[state]]
  outcomeStateOrder <- na.omit(arrange(outcomeState, desc(outcomeState[,outcomeKey]),Hospital.Name))
  goodData <- outcomeStateOrder[complete.cases(outcomeStateOrder) , ]
  View(goodData)
  
}

best("TX", "heart attack")
```

Comment: The character string "Not Available" does not identify a missing value in R. Missing values are designated by `NA`. Read the manual page at `?read.csv` and pay special attention to the `na.strings=` argument.

Comment: That is what I figured but I was unsure. Do i then need to use a for and if loop to remove those rows?

Comment: No. Use the `complete.cases()` function. It returns a logical vector which is TRUE if there are no missing values and FALSE if there are. Use that to extract only the complete cases from your data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case because "not available" is not the same as NA, I used the subset function to remove rows where the value was equal to "not available"

```
  goodData <- subset(outcomeState, outcomeState[, outcomeKey] != "Not Available")
```